# How to plot count of category columns of a dataframe based on timestamp column using any pandas visualization library

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like below

|  | test_case | test_type | source_path | table_path | test_status | record_count | table_partition | load_ts | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | check1 | T1 | /documents | /Status | pass | nan | nan | 2021-02-13 19:06:02.527 | 1 |
| 1 | check2 | T1 | /documents | /Status | fail | nan | nan | 2021-02-11 19:06:02.527 | 2 |
| 2 | check3 | T2 | /documents | /Status | pass | nan | nan | 2021-02-12 19:06:02.527 | 3 |
| 3 | check4 | T2 | /documents | /Status | fail | nan | nan | 2021-02-12 19:06:02.527 | 4 |

I want my Output or Visualization Plots which tell:
For each date(load_ts column),show test case names which have passed and test case names which have failed

I have tried the below code  -

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(15,16))
sns.countplot(x='load_ts', hue="test_status", data=result_df)

plt.show()
```

The problem with this code is that it only shows test status count of pass and fail per date but i want to further drill down and see that which test cases are under pass and which are under fail. Kindly see the below plot which i have created as of now.

[image: current plot]

Comment: hey, deleted my answer cause I think I misunderstood the question, sorry for that, hopefuly others could help

Comment: no issues, do you have any idea how it can be achieved?